# "await()" внутри "await()"а или как получить "parent scope"? Kotlin

Tags: многопоточность, kotlin, coroutine

Есть функция:

```
suspend fun getChats() {
    val chatList = mutableListOf<Chat>()
    getMyChats { chats ->
        chats.forEach {
            it.getDetail().await()
        }
    }.await()
}
```

Но компилятор ругается что `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` для `await()` который находится внутри `forEach` цикла. Как сделать чтоб работало?

Answer (score 0):

Ну уберите модификатор suspend c вашей функции. await() или async() вызывается из корутины. Когда же вы указываете ключевое слово suspend вы говорите, что эта функция будет вызвана из корутины где-то в другом месте.

Вот пример кода:

```
private val parentJob by lazy { Job() }

protected val backgroundScope: CoroutineScope by lazy { CoroutineScope(parentJob + Dispatchers.IO) }

fun coroutineFun() {
    backgroundScope.launch {
        someFun()
    }
}

private suspend fun someFun() {
    //do something
}
```

Вот [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/alfa/blog/336228/) и [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/421473/) можно почитать больше.